# Paypal Rest API and Lightbox

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to get the Paypal in-context lightbox workflow to work with their REST API.  I've been following instructions provided here:
https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/checkoutnow/how-to/ht-Hermes-xo

However, the lightbox does not seem to be working.  The behavior I see is that the curtain comes up, the modal briefly appears and then disappears.

Comment: You will be more likely to get an answer if you ad some code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The REST PayPal payment process is not currently supported to work within a lightbox or iframe.

A bunch of new features are planned to roll out this year for the REST API calls. I'm not sure if access to use the lightbox will be available though - sorry.